# Re-render form if array changes with React-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have a form for adding a cocktail recipe. I am using React-Hook-Form to build it. One of the sections is list of ingredients. For a start there should be only a single row. If the "Add ingredient" button is clicked, another row should show.

I can get it to add a row, but I cannot get it to re-render, when that happens. I am aware that I could probably do it with `useState`, but I cannot figure out how to use that with React-Hook-Forms, if that's even possible.

Here is how it looks in the initial render:

[image: Ingredients at initial render.]

And after clicking the "Tilføj ingediens" (add ingredient), it should look like this:

[image: Desired outcome after cliking "Add ingredient".]

However, this doesn't happen. From using `console.log` it appears that the ingredients array is in fact updated. It just doesn't re-render the form. Does anyone know how to do that, without abusing React (like triggering a re-render by changing some hidden component, etc.)? I have tried looking into the `watch` feature of React-Hook-Forms. It feels like a step in the right direction, but I cannot figure out how exactly it can be done.

## Code

```
import FileInput from "../components/FileInput";
import Input from "../components/Input";
import Label from "../components/Label";
import TextArea from "../components/TextArea";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

interface Cocktail {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    ingredients: Ingredient[];
}

interface Ingredient {
    name: string;
    quantity: string;
    unit: string;
}

const CreateCocktail = () => { 
    const {register, getValues, handleSubmit} = useForm<Cocktail>({ 
        defaultValues: { 
            name: '',
            description: '',
            imageUrl: '',
            ingredients: [
                {name: '', quantity: '', unit: ''}, {name: '', quantity: '', unit: ''}
            ]
        } 
    });

    const onAddIngredient = () => {
        // This part should somehow trigger a re-render of the form.
        console.log("Adding ingredient");
        getValues().ingredients.push({name: '', quantity: '', unit: ''});
    }
    
    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Cocktail> = async data => {
        try {
            console.log("Submitting cocktail", data);

            data.description = "Test description";
            data.imageUrl = "Test image url";

            const response = await fetch('/api/cocktails', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Cocktail created');
            } else {
                console.log('Error creating cocktail');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >  
                        // Rest of the form isn't relevant for this example                      
                        <Label htmlFor="ingredients" text="Ingredienser" />                            
                        <div>
                            {getValues().ingredients.map(() => (
                            <div key={Math.random()}>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Lys rom" />
                                
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    placeholder="60" />

                                <select>
                                    <option value="ml">ml</option>
                                    <option value="dashes">stænk</option>
                                    <option value="stk">stk</option>    
                                </select>                 
                            </div>
                            ))} 
                            <div>
                                <button 
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={onAddIngredient}>
                                    Tilføj ingrediens
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                                            
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" 
                            value="Gem" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default CreateCocktail;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

The code you provided uses `getValues` incorrectly, as it cannot update hookform values via `getValues`(get is only for fetching current values). Instead, we must use `setValue` to change form values.

Furthermore, if you want to get real-time/onChange updates from hook-form values you cannot use `getValues` (this only gets the current value when called but does not update when changed), you must use `watch` for this instead.

Refer to the code below for a working example of what you are trying to achieve.

### Solution

```
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";

interface Cocktail {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    ingredients: Ingredient[];
}

interface Ingredient {
    name: string;
    quantity: string;
    unit: string;
}

export const CreateCocktail = () => { 
    const { getValues, handleSubmit, setValue, watch} = useForm<Cocktail>({ 
        defaultValues: { 
            name: '',
            description: '',
            imageUrl: '',
            ingredients: [
                {name: '', quantity: '', unit: ''}, {name: '', quantity: '', unit: ''}
            ]
        } 
    });
    //create a watch for ingredients, you could also pass a string array to watch multiple values if needed
    const IngridientsList = watch('ingredients')
    //update item on click via setValue
    const onAddIngredient = () => {
        setValue('ingredients', [...getValues('ingredients'), {name: '', quantity: '', unit: ''}])
    }
    
    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Cocktail> = async data => {
        try {
            console.log("Submitting cocktail", data);

            data.description = "Test description";
            data.imageUrl = "Test image url";

            const response = await fetch('/api/cocktails', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Cocktail created');
            } else {
                console.log('Error creating cocktail');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >  
                        <div>
                            {IngridientsList.map(() => (
                            <div key={Math.random()}>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Lys rom" />
                                
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    placeholder="60" />

                                <select>
                                    <option value="ml">ml</option>
                                    <option value="dashes">stænk</option>
                                    <option value="stk">stk</option>    
                                </select>                 
                            </div>
                            ))} 
                            <div>
                                <button 
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={onAddIngredient}>
                                    Tilføj ingrediens
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                                            
                    
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" 
                            value="Gem" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default CreateCocktail;
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to use `setValue` method to update form values not `getValues.push()`. Second `getValues` will not trigger rerender, you need to use `watch` and pass the name of field that you want to listen i.e. `ingredients`. If you do not pass the name to `watch` then it returns all form values.

Here's the complete code.

```
import { type SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

interface Cocktail {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    ingredients: Array<Ingredient>;
}

interface Ingredient {
    name: string;
    quantity: string;
    unit: string;
}

const CreateCocktail = () => {
    const { getValues, handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm<Cocktail>({
        defaultValues: {
            name: '',
            description: '',
            imageUrl: '',
            ingredients: [{ name: '', quantity: '', unit: '' }]
        }
    });

    const onAddIngredient = () => {
        setValue('ingredients', [...getValues().ingredients, { name: '', quantity: '', unit: '' }]);
    };

    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Cocktail> = async (data) => {
        try {
            console.log('Submitting cocktail', data);

            data.description = 'Test description';
            data.imageUrl = 'Test image url';

            const response = await fetch('/api/cocktails', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Cocktail created');
            } else {
                console.log('Error creating cocktail');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <label htmlFor='ingredients'>Ingredienser</label>
            <div>
                {watch('ingredients').map(() => (
                    <div key={Math.random()}>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Lys rom' />

                        <input type='text' placeholder='60' />

                        <select>
                            <option value='ml'>ml</option>
                            <option value='dashes'>stænk</option>
                            <option value='stk'>stk</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                ))}
                <div>
                    <button type='button' onClick={onAddIngredient}>
                        Tilføj ingrediens
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type='submit' value='Gem' />
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};

export default CreateCocktail;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called `Dynamic Form`.
Using `setValue` and `getValue` might be very tricky.
You should use `useFieldArray` hook from `react-hook-form`.
I wrote something for you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-49kn8n?file=src%2FApp.tsx) so you can see the exact usage.
BTW [this](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usefieldarray) is a link to documentation.
And [this](https://youtu.be/4MrbfGSFY2A) is a link to a good video make by the creator of `react-hook-form`.
Hope it helps.